# Display last modification date for non-Wordpress website in Google Search results

Tags: seo, html

I have a simple HTML+PHP website. Google prefers the fresh content in my niche .. but I don't know how can I tell google the published date or the last modified date of any page on my website.

I searched a lot about the way but I can't find anything, most of content talking about WordPress SEO plugins. I want to display the last modification date beside my webpage description exactly like this:

[image]

Is it a JavaScript code or HTML code or meta tag code, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify your dates, use the **[HTML element `time` with the attribute `datetime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time)**.
Use the **[ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** format to specify the value of this attribute, specifying the **[UTC offset](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)** for your locale, e.g.:

```
<time datetime="2022-05-01T09:00+01:00">May 1, 2022</time>
```

Read more **[Dates and times](https://developers.google.com/style/dates-times)** from Google.

For structured data markup, use **[DateTime](https://schema.org/DateTime)**.